# how to move the scrollbar down the page to a particular coordinate when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

Hi Guys for some reasons the scrollTo doesn't work for me at all when i tried to move the scrollbar down to bring a certain section of my page to focus
This is my code.

```
var xplore = document.querySelector('.btn-explore');
    xplore.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 785);
      }
    )
```

Can anyone help me out here? The page just doesnt scroll at all, Or is it something with my css, do i need position or overflow property?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When are you running this code? If you have it in the `head`, the rest of the page hasn't loaded so `xplore` would likely be null.

Comment: not in the head i actually added an alert that ran after the code for scroll  has ran

Comment: Perhaps you could include a [mcve] in a Stack Snippet (button in the editor looks like `<>`)? That would make it easier to answer your question without guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that your `body` or `html` tag does not have a large enough height to scroll through.

```css
body, html{
  height: 785px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-explore">Explore</button>
<script>
var xplore = document.querySelector('.btn-explore');
xplore.addEventListener('click', function() {
     window.scrollTo(0, 785);
   }
)
</script>
```

If you want to scroll to a position smoothly in a certain amount of milliseconds, you can use `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

```css
body, html{
  height: 785px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-explore">Explore</button>
<script>
var xplore = document.querySelector('.btn-explore');
xplore.addEventListener('click', function() {
     scrollToSmoothly(785, 500);
   }
)
/*
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: pal my page does'nt scroll at all, there are large enough place to scroll to

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try something like this in your css. .box is a box where your content is shown and made scrollable:

```
.Box {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And in the Code I use:

```
$(".Box").scrollTop($(".Box")[0].scrollHeight);
```

It  is written in JQuery.

I am by far no pro myself but I hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks pal, But I had like to do this without jQuery